# Latex formatting a pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I have this matlab code  and i want to write it's pseudo code in latex, how can i convey the same message as this code. The code is given below

```
   for i=1:32
   if(1<=i&&i<=16)

    z=circshift(b,mod(i,8),2);

    c=bitxor(bitor(bitand(a,b),c),d);
    c=sprintf('%d',c);

T=dec2bin(mod(bin2dec(z)+ bin2dec(sprintf('%d',bitxor(bitand(bitxor(bitand(a,b),c),d),e)))+bin2dec(c)+bin2dec(W(i,:)),256),8);
e=d;
d=c;
c=circshift(c,5,2);
b=a;
a=T;
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think this is a job for `listings` or `minted`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package [`matlab-prettifier`](https://ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]
   for i=1:32
   if(1<=i&&i<=16)

    z=circshift(b,mod(i,8),2);

    c=bitxor(bitor(bitand(a,b),c),d);
    c=sprintf('%d',c);

T=dec2bin(mod(bin2dec(z)+ bin2dec(sprintf('%d',bitxor(bitand(bitxor(bitand(a,b),c),d),e)))+bin2dec(c)+bin2dec(W(i,:)),256),8);
e=d;
d=c;
c=circshift(c,5,2);
b=a;
a=T;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]